# Gram-Schmidt process when metric is not an Euclidean

Tags: differential-geometry

Can we use a Gram-Schmidt process for finding an orthogonal vector if a metric on a space is not an Euclidean one?

These are the vectors and the metric.
If we have the next two vectors:
\begin{align}
\notag
A_{1}=c_{1}y_{1}^{2}y_{2}^{2}u(u+2t)(u+y_{2}^{2})\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}},
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\notag
A=-c_{11}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}-c_{12}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}-\frac{u(u+2t)}{u+y_{2}^{2}}(c_{8}(u+y_{1}^{2})+c_{1}y_{1}y_{2})\frac{\partial}{\partial y_{1}},
\end{align}
and the metric
\begin{align}
\notag
G=
\begin{pmatrix}
u+vy_{1}^{2} & vy_{1}y_{2} & 0& 0 \\
vy_{1}y_{2} & u+vy_{2}^{2} & 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{u+vy_{2}^{2}}{u(u+2tv)}& -\frac{vy_{1}y_{2}}{u(u+2tv)}\\
0& 0& -\frac{vy_{1}y_{2}}{u(u+2tv)} & \frac{u+vy_{1}^{2}}{u(u+2tv)} ,
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
If we use Gram-Schmidt in this case, we get a vector which is orthogonal to $A_{1}$ but not to $A$.\
On the other hand, we can find vectors that span a normal bundle of a submanifold generated by $A_{1}$ and $A$, using an almost complex structure.\
We need to find a normal component of a given vector with respect to $A_{1}$ and $A$, that is why we need a vector that is orthogonal to $A_{1}$ and $A$. So, my other question would be is one of the vectors in the normal bundle enough for finding mentioned component?

Thank you!

Comment: What definition of orthogonality are you using? $\;$

Comment: If $G$ is a metric which is not an Euclidean, then $X$ and $Y$ are orthogonal if $G(X,Y)=0$.

Comment: That is not a good definition of orthogonality. For orthogonality, you need a metric space and a dot product. Anyway, by your definition, the vectors $X$ and $Y$ are orthogonal if and only if they are equal.

Comment: @5xum: I believe he is using the terminology from differential geometry where a Riemannian metric is a smoothly varying inner product on each tangent space of a manifold.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I believe so too, but I am trying to get through to him with the message that he needs to ask his questions properly. He said that $G$ is a metric. By definition of a metric, that means that $G(x,y)$ is the distance between $x$ and $y$. I am answering the questions he asked, not those I guess he might have wanted to ask.

Comment: @NovakDjokovic: Can you explain a bit your notation? For example, what is your manifold? What are those $y_i$, $u$, $t$, and $v$'s?

Answer (score 1):

In the exact same way, but instead of using the dot product, you use whatever inner product you're given.

**Example:** Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the inner product

$$\langle (x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2)\rangle = 2x_1y_1 + x_1y_2 + x_2y_1 + 3x_2y_2.$$

Given the basis $\{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, what do we get when we apply the Gram-Schmidt process? As

$$\|(1, 0)\|^2 = \langle (1, 0), (1, 0)\rangle = 2(1)(1) + (1)(0) + (0)(1) + 3(0)(0) = 2,$$

$u_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, 0)$. Now

\begin{align*}
u_2' &= (0, 1) - \left\langle (0, 1), \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, 0)\right\rangle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, 0)\\ 
&= (0, 1) - \left(2(0)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+(0)(0)+(1)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+3(1)(0)\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,0)\\ 
&= (0,1)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,0)\\
&= (0,1) - \frac{1}{2}(1, 0)\\
&= \left(-\frac{1}{2}, 1\right)
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
\|u_2'\|^2 &= \left\|\left(-\frac{1}{2},1\right)\right\|^2\\ 
&= \left\langle\left(-\frac{1}{2},1\right), \left(-\frac{1}{2},1\right)\right\rangle\\ 
&= 2\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) + \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)(1) + (1)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)+3(1)(1)\\ 
&= \frac{5}{2}
\end{align*}

so $u_2 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}}(-\frac{1}{2}, 1)$. So an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, with the inner product above is

$$\{u_1, u_2\} = \left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, 0), \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{5}}\left(-\frac{1}{2}, 1\right)\right\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

For the Gram-Schmidt process, you need two things:

- A vector space with a dot (scalar) product.
- A set of vectors.

So yes, the metric need not be euclidian (you can, for example, find orthogonal polynomials for the cross product $$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx,$$
however, just a metric space, as you wrote, is not enough.

Comment: So what could be a problem, because if I use Gram-Schmidt, I get a vector which is orthogonal just to one of my vectors but on the second it is not.

Comment: Huh? If you use Gram-Schmidt on a set of vectors $\{v_1,v_2\dots,v_n\}$, you get a set of vectors $\{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$ which is pairwise orthogonal. I don't know what you mean by your comment.

Comment: I will try to explain it in more detail in my next question.

Comment: NO! Edit your question. Do not spam questions for one single problem.